# Get a Count from a MYSQL Inquire

Tags: mysql

I'm pretty novice at MYSQL, but I'm attempting to get a count from a MYSQL select I already have.
Pretty much, I'd like to count the number of items, then group them by what their locations.locationID is then display the locations.Name.

Here is what I have(kinda a mess). This gets drives with greater the 5000MB and displays them.

```
Select DISTINCT 
  'C'
  , computers.computerid
  , computers.Name as ComputerName
  , Convert(CONCAT(clients.name,' ',locations.name) Using utf8) As Location
  , drives.`Size` as TestValue,0 
FROM ((drives 
LEFT JOIN Computers ON Computers.ComputerID=drives.ComputerID) 
LEFT JOIN Locations ON Locations.LocationID=Computers.Locationid)
LEFT JOIN Clients ON Clients.ClientID=Computers.clientid 
JOIN AgentComputerData on Computers.ComputerID=AgentComputerData.ComputerID 
WHERE drives.`Size` > 5000 AND  (1)  
AND Computers.ComputerID NOT IN 
  (Select ComputerID from AgentIgnore Where AgentID=0);
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I replaced the lefts win inners because the results make no sense if you are missing a relationship in any of the tables. Also I recommend doing any charset conversion on the scripting side if it's an option, and if you only need one encoding anyway, encode the table that way to begin with.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumDrives
     , CONCAT(clients.name,' ',locations.name) As Location 
  FROM drives 
 INNER  
  JOIN Computers 
    ON Computers.ComputerID=drives.ComputerID 
   AND drives.`Size` > 5000
 INNER 
  JOIN AgentComputerData on Computers.ComputerID=AgentComputerData.ComputerID     
 INNER 
  JOIN Locations 
    ON Locations.LocationID=Computers.Locationid
 INNER  
  JOIN Clients 
    ON Clients.ClientID=Computers.clientid 
 WHERE Computers.ComputerID 
   NOT 
    IN (Select ComputerID from AgentIgnore Where AgentID=0) 
 GROUP
    BY CONCAT(clients.name,' ',locations.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
  count(*) as ItemCount
  ,Locations.Name
FROM drives 
LEFT JOIN Computers ON Computers.ComputerID = drives.ComputerID
LEFT JOIN Locations ON Locations.LocationID = Computers.Locationid
LEFT JOIN Clients ON Clients.ClientID = Computers.clientid 
JOIN AgentComputerData on Computers.ComputerID = AgentComputerData.ComputerID 
WHERE drives.`Size` > 5000
AND Computers.ComputerID NOT IN 
  (Select ComputerID from AgentIgnore Where AgentID=0);
GROUP BY Locations.LocationID
```

I've tried to stick to your description as close as I could. Hope this is what you need.